# wordpress search results issues

Tags: php, wordpress

i am working on a search page and i want to return a data with just few lines from that page or post contents. i can do this with php but i am looking for the the solution from the wordpress side. i searched for it but no satisfactory results.

below is the code which display the contents

```
<div class="testimonial-content">
    <div class="thumb search_page_individual_contents">
        <?php the_content();?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

as the_content() would display all the content if any one is fount but i want it to display only first three lines from that page or post.

Comment: no comment yet after 7 views so strange

Comment: its been first time happening with me that i am still waiting for reply after 10 views and 9 minutes on stackoverflow

Comment: i dont know if my question is wrong let me know plz

Comment: That's what the `the_excerpt` function is for. Check http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt

Comment: yes this was the solution thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you please used this code where your serach result display :

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

**And Add this line of code in function.php**

```
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
       global $post;
    return '... <a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">Read more</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');


function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the [wp_trim_words()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words)

```
<?php
   echo wp_trim_words(the_content(), 40, 
                            '<a href="'. get_permalink() .'"> ...Read More</a>');
?>
```